# How to properly extend interface?

Tags: c++

I have interface based on another:

```
class IDrawable {
public:
   virtual ~IDrawable();
};

class IExtendedDrawable: public IDrawable {
public:
   virtual ~IExtendedDrawable();
};

class DrawableImplementation: public IDrawable {
public:
   virtual ~DrawableImplementation();
};

class ExtendedDrawableImplementation: 
   public DrawableImplementation, public IExtendedDrawable
{
public:
   virtual ~ExtendedDrawableImplementation();
};
```

Then `ExtendedDrawableImplementation` = `DrawableImplementation (+IDrawable)` + `IExtendedDrawable (+IDrawable)`

Is it right to have `IDrawable` twice in same class?

Comment: You might need to use virtual inheritance here as this looks like multiple inheritance in a diamond shape

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give the benefit of the doubt that you DO indeed need/want multiple inheritance.  I see it as good in only limited situations, and interfaces is one of them (even Java allows this).

As said above, use virtual inheritance and be sure to only use pure `virtual` methods in the interface `class`es.

```
class IDrawable {
public:
   virtual ~IDrawable();
   virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class IExtendedDrawable: virtual public IDrawable {
public:
   virtual ~IExtendedDrawable();
   virtual void doSomethingElse() = 0;
};

class DrawableImplementation: virtual public IDrawable {
public:
   virtual ~DrawableImplementation();
   virtual void doSomething() {/*code here*/}
};

class ExtendedDrawableImplementation: 
   public DrawableImplementation, public IExtendedDrawable
{
public:
   virtual ~ExtendedDrawableImplementation();
   virtual void doSomething() {/*code here*/}
   virtual void doSomethingElse() {/*code here*/}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It largely depends on the logic inside the classes is, but IMO you're better off using composition instead:

```
class ExtendedDrawableImplementation : public IExtendedDrawable
{
   IDrawable* drawableImplementation; //points to a DrawableImplementation
public:
   virtual ~ExtendedDrawableImplementation();
};
```

Multiple inheritance is rarely the answer.

Comment: `DrawableImplementation` implements `IDrawable` functions and `ExtendedDrawableImplementation` implements `IExtendedDrawable` functions

Comment: @Miro I understood that, but it still doesn't explain the underlying logic. Is `ExtendedDrawableImplementation` really an `IExtendedDrawable`? Inheritance is a `is-a` relationship. From a logic point of view.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore  I think the "interfaces" is one exception where multiple inheritance can be valid.

Comment: @MartyE define valid. C++ allows multiple inheritance from concrete classes, not just interfaces. I wasn't talking about language validity, but logical validity.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore understood about language validity vs logical validity.  I should clarify my comment is that "interfaces" using the term loosely is one exception where it _may_ make sense for multiple inheritance.  The best example I can think of is from my GUI days where I wanted one object to listen for mouse click events on another object and mouse-over events on another object and had to register as two different interfaces.

Comment: @MartyE a single objects listening to two types of events, at least how you described it, breaks the single-responsibility rule. So it's not really a good design imo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just derive `ExtendedDrawableImplementation` from `IExtendedDrawable`. That way it will have both interfaces anyway. I don't see why you would want to derive from both here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not C++ programmer, but from what I remember, it's correct. You don't have IDrawable twice, but you have multiple path to it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem#The_diamond_problem